# IJCADの.netでモデル空間の図面範囲設定したい

Tags: vb.net, ijcad

IJCAD2019でVB.net開発をしています。
通常の描画ではモデル空間の図面範囲を行う場合、LIMITコマンドを使用しますが、.netの場合はどのようなメソッドを使用するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database.Limcheck プロパティ、Database.Limmax プロパティ、Database.Limmin プロパティを変更することでモデル空間の図面範囲を変更することが可能です。